# Azure - queueing time based tasks

Tags: c#, azure, queue, scheduled-tasks, azure-worker-roles

My application that runs on Windows Azure processes incoming requests from a user (which are put into an Azure Queue) and assigns them to real-world people.

The people have a certain amount of time to handle the request. If none of the people assigned handle the request, I need to move on to a new set of people. Basically, I want to queue these tasks to be handled at a certain time, and then handle them again. If one of the users handles the task, I need to dequeue it so it isn't handled again by the worker.

Comment: this question is interesting. i am working on similar project too. still seeking for answers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a scheduled task. There are two good libraries out there that you could use:
[Quartz.Net](http://quartznet.sourceforge.net/) and
[Castle scheduler](http://stw.castleproject.org/%28S%28ta5wga45q0nwdif0d3vk0saf%29%29/Tools.Scheduler.ashx).

With a scheduledler, such a task becomes easy.
You just create a job that runs when the processing time expires. There you would check for any unprocessed requests and if there are any left, you notify the next set of people and set another scheduled start to fire after processing time expires.

Let me know if you need further detail.

I've used Quartz.net in an azure webrole successfully in a production app.

Comment: How does this scale? What if you are running 10 web roles concurrently? Wouldn't this create a massive duplication of work?

Comment: Mark, this is a good remark. The scheduler would indeed by running in every single instance. When the scheduled job is triggered you would just push a message on the azure queue and leave it up to the worker roles. You could peek to see if the same message already exists. But still there is a chance that multiple equal messages would be on the azure queue. That is why you should always strive for idempotency in your design -> in this case that means that your system is immune to  processing the message multiple times.

Comment: Sometimes idempotency isn't possible. In my case, I need something more resilient than this.

Comment: @Mark Seemann: If my understanding of your problem is correct, you should run the scheduled tasks in one (or more) workerrole which will be feed by queue messages.

Comment: @santiagoIT: I completely agree with you when it comes to the importance of idempotency. Still, kicking off 10 idempotent (but identical) jobs seems wasteful to me. On Azure, it's even very likely to be 10 times as expensive as if you could kick off just one single job.

Comment: Mark, you can almost entirely avoid this if you peek the queue before pushing a job on it. What I normally do is add some random delay 0-20s to the time the job trigger time (to avoid all instances terminating at the exact same time). If you then peek the queue it is very unlikely that you end up running duplicate jobs. For me idempotency is paramount and I can live with the rare case duplicate processing.