# Automatically download and fill SQL Server table from .csv

Tags: .net, sql-server, asp.net-mvc-2, csv

So this site - http://www.stopforumspam.com/downloads/, has a file available for download containing IP addresses linked with spam accounts on the web.

I have a table in my SQL Server database containing a list of blocked IP's for use with my comment system checking.

Is there anyway (or anything I can look into), to get my web app to go and download this file once a day at midnight, and re-fresh my table with the data in this .csv file?

Thanks guys.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would probably use WebClient.DownloadFile as Stefan suggested, but I would create my own script to import the data. I have not used the application he referenced, but creating your own script allows you to validate the data before inserting it. You could also programatically check to see what has changed before inserting, and only insert new records.

Since you're using Azure, you can create scheduled tasks as described in this question: [Azure - queueing time based tasks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4824193/azure-queueing-time-based-tasks)

Answer (score 0):

You can use [WebClient.DownloadFile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe.aspx) to get the cvs on your server and then use code from this [project](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/database/Cs_CSV_import_export.aspx) to export your csv file to sql.

If you want the code that does the above operations to run each day, is better to create a windows service with a timer on service start that triggers every 24h. good luck

Comment: I'm running my app on Azure though, so this would probably be a little weird right?